# How do I connect an external display to my Macbook Pro?

Tags: display, hdmi, vga-adapter

I have a Macbook Pro (Late 2013). I'm trying to mirror the display on a [LG M2035A](http://www.lg.com/id/monitor/lg-20M35A). The monitor accepts VGA input. The monitor comes with a VGA cable. So, I purchased a HDMI to VGA converter, to connect to the monitor. However, my Macbook doesn't seem to detect the external display. I think my VGA and HDMI cable function properly, because when I connect the monitor using this to my laptop running Windows, it functions perfectly. Is there a workaround, or something I'm missing?

Comment: Why would you say it only accepts VGA and then ask about DVI? What connectors physically exist on the device?

Comment: @bmike  Sorry I was just going to edit the question haha. I wanted to enquire about that too.

Comment: Also - there are lots of flavors of MacBook in a model year. Does yours use HDMI or thunderbolt for connecting to this specific monitor/adapter?

Answer (score 1):

DVI is far, far superior in terms of the Mac sensing the capabilities of the display and in terms of quality. Go that method if you can.

If your VGA adapter isn't working with OS X, you could contact the adapter vendor for support. Not all of them are high quality and even the high quality ones don't work with all displays/projectors.

Comment: Thanks! I just read up, and I now know that the monitor accepts only VGA input. Should I purchase a different VGA cable and try it out?

Comment: @AkashSubramanian Tough call. I like to take the adapter and the Mac to a VGA display I know works and test. Troubleshooting is just changing one thing and retesting. Isolating the component that is not compatible/faulty/set up properly.